# discord.js-commando RangeError: Argument type "string" isn't registered

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I'm trying to disable default help and eval command in commando however, I get the following error:

```
RangeError: Argument type "string" isn't registered.
```

I registered `discord.js-commando` as client

That's the code that the error is from

```
client.registry.registerDefaultCommands({
    help: false,
    eval: false,
});
```

Comment: that error is not related to default commands the problem is with some argument type you registered in some command. Errro: https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/198d7604e3725ee88dceab9b5f296edb1b7580a5/src/commands/argument.js#L396,
Class Argument

Answer (score 0):

I looked on the documents and I figured out the problem.
The issue is that you were only registering the default commands, but you also needed to register the default types and the default groups.
Add these few lines of code to fix the problem:

```js
    .registerDefaultTypes()
    .registerDefaultGroups()
    .registerDefaultCommands({
      // Put commands you dont want to use here
})
```

Read more about the issue [here:https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoRegistry?scrollTo=registerDefaultCommands](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/CommandoRegistry?scrollTo=registerDefaultCommands)

Comment: Well now im getting `Error: An argument type with the ID "string" is already registered.`